# Suggestions for attempting to rotate an image in the header

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, atom-editor

I want an image to rotate about 45 degrees. I'm working in Atom with Bootstrap. I have tried looking on the documentation however, I have not found anything that addresses that challenge.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You need to bring some code to the table if you want help as people won't write code for you. If Bootstrap won't do what you want, ask Google. The answer is there. Remember that Bootstrap is just CSS (with some JS). If you still can't make it work, bring the code you tried and someone will help.

Comment: How is your editor relevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a CSS transform property to rotate your image 45 degrees.

```
.your-image-class {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```